# Help designing a serial adder

Tags: flipflop, shift-register, adder

I need to build a circuit that adds two n-bit 2's complement numbers. the two numbers have to be stored in shift registers. The circuit should start with the least significant bits of each number and add each pair of bits using an adder. The sum bit from the adder will then be stored into one of the registers. WE need to use 2 shift registers, an adder and one dflipflop.

Comment: You must show some effort, you can't expect us to solve your homework.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to be a homework in which you don't show that you tried anything before posting I will just lead you to the answer, although you could have found it with a simple Google search.

Everything you need can be found in those two links:

[Registers and Counters](http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~gerousis/courses/CPEN214/Registers.pdf)

[4-Bit Binary Adder / EE 584 – Introduction to VLSI](http://www.engr.uky.edu/~elias/projects/12.pdf)